# Tile provider with access token (Jawg) in R Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying with the following code to get the Jawg.Light tiles on my map. However, i guess the passing of the access token fails.

```
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("Jawg.Light", options = providerTileOptions(accessToken=ac))
```

This code share just an empty map, like if no access token is given.
[image]

Unfortunately I cannot make it more reproduceable since I cannot share the access token.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Currently running into the same issue but all relevant answers aren't in R.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`addTiles("https://{s}.tile.jawg.io/jawg-light/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?access-token={accessToken}")`

With your access token in place of `{accessToken}` in the url.

Comment: I'm currently have the same issue. It appears to not working inside the `addProviderTiles()`. Since `url` in `addTiles` is a string, I'm using `paste0` to combine the access token

Comment: Oh itworks. So with `addTiles` no need to write `addProviderTiles`. Got it